# Newton Raphson interval choice for multiple roots

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence

I am using Newton Raphson to find the roots of multiple polynomials as part of a homework exercise. However, for polynomials that have complex roots I don't understand how to select the intervals to calculate the answers.

**For example**, $x^7-1=0$.

Obviously one solution is $x=1$, and can get the formula:

$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac {x^7-1}{7x^6}$

However I am unsure what starting values with give me the solutions.

Comment: You could try Durand Kerner method which gives all roots, with my (limited) experience it seems to be quite robust provided you give complex initial guesses. But if you have to utilise the Newton method, it is probably possible but that fails me at the moment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the equation $x^7 - 1 = 0$, we have the $7^{th}$ roots of unity. These are given by:

$$x=1,-\sqrt[7]{-1},(-1)^{2/7},-(-1)^{3/7},(-1)^{4/7},-(-1)^{5/7},(-1)^{6/7}$$

Numerically, these are:

$x=1., 0.62349\, +0.781831 i, -0.222521+0.974928 i, -0.900969+0.433884 i, -0.900969-0.433884 i, -0.222521-0.974928 i, 0.62349\, -0.781831 i$

Graphically, we can show these as:

[image]

We can use Newton's Method to find the real and the imaginary roots. The Newton iteration formula is given by:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x_n -\dfrac{x_n^7 - 1}{7 x_n^6}$$

Note, we only need to find three of the complex root plus the real one for a total of four given the complex roots come in conjugate pairs. You can choose the starting point randomly until you get the real and three complex roots. I tried using the picture above to choose points closer to the roots, but the reality is that it is not very instructive.

**Root 1**

- $x_0 = 0.5 , \ldots, x_{21} = 1. $

**Root 2**

- $x_0 = 0.5 - 0.25 i, \ldots, x_{15}  =  -0.9009688679024191+0.4338837391175582 i $$

**Root 3**

- $x_0 = 0 + 0.5 i, \ldots, x_{23}  =  -0.2225209339563144+0.9749279121818236 i $$

**Root 4**

- $x_0 = 1 + i , \ldots, x_7 =  0.6234898018587335+0.7818314824680298 i $

You may also want to explore other [*root finding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_all_roots_at_once) algorithms that can find all roots at once or that are better suited for complex numbers.